# How do you change the star rating image from WooCoomerce to another image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rating-system, icon-fonts

So, I've been developing an ecommerce site for a winery.

As you know, WooCommerce uses stars as a rating symbol. The customer doesn't want the star rating system, since in his niche stars are for brandys and other similar liquors.

So, how can I change the stars to another symbol? (I know it's an icon font)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

go to themes/your theme name/ style.css

and change the color code to following.

```
.star-rating span:before {
     color:#ffcc1c;
}
```